# Where's the StackExchange Inbox?

Tags: support

I often see an attention-seeking indicator in the upper left corner of the page at the 'StackExchange' drop-down menu, and when I click on it there's another indicator within stating there are (presumably unread) messages in my inbox.

-

However when I click on it there is no response.

Moreover my account page does not appear to include anything to the effect of an 'Inbox'.

Nor does the 'New here? Sign up!' message bar pop-up to indicate any unacknowledged activity.

-

Where are these indicators documented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The stackexchange inbox can be found by clicking in the top left and then clicking on inbox.

[image]

The per-site inbox can be found by clicking on the envelope and then clicking on a time interval if what your are interested in isn't already displayed.

[image]

Comment: +4 For four [freehand circles.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775)

Comment: Great, thanks. The Cross-site inbox icon you mentioned first is the one that doesn't work right now, but the other one does. I just overlooked that.

Comment: I notice now that the cross-site inbox that drops-down, will contain the most recent item at the top of the list. I was expecting to click on the 'Inbox' icon inside it to do something.

Comment: @Zoredache, This answer doesn't work anymore. There is no link to the inbox in the top left dropdown. Do you have a direct link to the page?

Comment: No, I don't know where that exists anymore.  I am not even sure if it does really.